# how can I select last loaded tag with a particular class.(not :last)

Tags: javascript, jquery

let's start with an example:

```
<p class="paragraph"> some text </p>
<script> here must be the script that adds class to the above p </script>
<p class="paragraph"> some other text </p>
<script> here must be the script that adds class to the above p </script>
...
```

I want to add a class to the "p" which is before the "script". The script tag can also be inside the paragraph, but it isn't supposed to be before. I hope it is clear now but if not clear I'd be glad to give you further information about my question. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The script has no clue where it is in relation to the flow of the page. Best you can do is select all of the tags you are looking for and select the last one.

---

JavaScript:

```
var elems = document.getElementsByClassName("paragraph");
console.log(elems[elems.length-1])
```

jQuery:

```
$(".paragraph").last().addClass("foo");
```

Comment: I tried :last but it wasn't practical, if I realized you true. thanks anyway :)

Comment: Was is it not practical? Best solution would be to not have to do it this way. :)

Comment: Woa!!! Really THANKS. I don't know most of Jquery functions yet! It worked perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

use getElementsByTagName and get the length of the returned list, it will be the index of last loaded tag. eg:

```
<p class="paragraph"> some text </p>
<script> here must be the script that adds class to the above p </script>
<p class="paragraph"> some other text </p>

    function getLastTag(){
    var list=document.getElementsByTagName('p');
    list[list.length-1].className='your class name';
    }
```

Comment: could you explain this more? I'm confused! the length is for the string in the p?

Comment: no, the getElementsByTagName('p') returns an array of dom elements which have p as the tag name. So the lenght is stands for no.of p elements in the document. Since the indexing is starting from zero, you have to put list.lenght-1 instead of list.length. Then you can have the last p element.

Answer (score 0):

You can select all the paragraphs at once and add the class you want, e.g. by using a data attribute:

Your html:

```
<p class="paragraph" data-class="foo">Some text</p>
<p class="paragraph" data-class="bar">Some other text</p>
```

Part of your script (assuming you use jQuery on load)

```
$('p.paragraph').each(function () {    
  $(this).addClass($(this).data('class'));
});
```

Comment: my problem is that I can't use the class that I want to add in the beginning. Otherwise I could directly add class at first. Thanks anyway :)

Comment: In that case you can set up a trigger that executes the `.each`, something like `$('#paragraph-wrapper').on('im-ready-to-add-the-classes', '.paragraph', function () { /* each loop comes here */ ...`